# Shortest paths in weighted graphs, and minimum spanning trees

Tags: graphs, trees, shortest-path, minimum-spanning-tree

I stuck in one challenging question, I read on my notes.

> An undirected, weighted, connected graph $G$, (with no negative
>   weights and with all weights distinct) is given. We know that, in this graph,
>   the shortest path between any two vertices is on the minimum spanning tree (MST). Verify the following:
>
> 1) shortest path between any two vertices $u$, $v$ is unique.

My question is, is this statement (1) is false or True?

Other details is not mentioned in the old exam question, But I think:

1) if this means that for any pair of vertices and for any shortest path between them, it lies on MST So this statement is False. for example Let's assume that we have a graph with two vertices $\{1, 2\}$ and one edge between them with zero weight. There are infinitely many shortest paths between the first and the second vertex ($[1, 2]$, $[1, 2, 1, 2]$, ...)

2) if this means For each $a,b\in V$, for each shortest path $P$ from $a$ to $b$ in $G$ there exists a minimum spanning tree $T$ of $G$ such that $p$ is contained in $T$. this statement is True.

Comment: Usually, "path" means "simple path", i.e., a sequence $v_1\dots v_\ell$ of *distinct* vertices such that $v_1v_2, \dots, v_{\ell-1}v_{\ell}$ are edges. By that definition, $1212$ isn't a path so your example with a zero-weight edge only has one shortest path between the vertices. (Also, zero-weight edges are often implicitly forbidden by a convention that assigns weight zero to the absence of an edge.)

Comment: 1. Is your question "what is the definition of path"?  If so, (a) where have you looked to find the definition of path?  (it's often listed in textbooks); (b) if it wasn't listed in your textbook, that might be a better question (more likely to be useful to others in the future) than this very specific question.  2. I think you need to define "shortest path" carefully, if you want to make the question precise.  It looks like your notes aren't very precise about this (for instance, writing "the shortest path" is strictly speaking problematic, as the shortest path might not be unique).

Comment: You means my example is not correct, ok, under my interpretation (1), again is it false? @DavidRicherby

Comment: thanks @D.W. we dont want to play with words :) path is path. e consider simple path and path. just two case, we can overcome to these.

Comment: Your observation that a shortest path should lie on the MST is false.

Comment: @HendrikJan is right. Consider a 4-cycle of edge weights 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: @HendrikJan Shortest paths lying on the MST is the hypothesis of the question. Suppose we are given a graph that has a bunch of properties, including that the shortest path between any two vertices is on the MST: is there a unique shortest path between every pair of vertices?

Comment: @Bangye Shortest paths being on the MST is the hypothesis of the question. It's not an absolute truth; we're being asked to suppose we have a graph with the given property.

Comment: "Any shortest path must be on MST" or "there exists a shortest path on MST".

Comment: @DavidRicherby You are right, sorry. Now *the* shortest path bothers me, like mentioned in the comment by D.W. above.

Comment: @HendrikJan I agree -- see my comment to [superuseroi's answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/41198/9550). Voting to close as "unclear what you're asking."

Comment: @Bangye if we consider Any shortest path must be on MST The statement is True, if consider there exists a shortest path on MST this is false. am I right?

Comment: @DavidRicherby my last comment is correect?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1228205/14578

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the hypothesis of the question to try clarify every aspect:

Our Graph G should:

1. be undirected
2. be weighted
3. be connected
4. with no negative weights
5. with all weights distinct
6. in this graph, **the** shortest path between any two vertices is on the
   minimum spanning tree (MST)

I believe the key point here is the article used in point 6, as pointed out by [David Richerby comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41185/shortest-paths-in-weighted-graphs-and-minimum-spanning-trees/41198?noredirect=1#comment81886_41198)

From the wikipedia page: [Article (grammar)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)):

Definite Article

> A **definite article** indicates that its noun is a particular one (or
>   ones) identifiable to the listener. **It may be something that the
>   speaker has already mentioned, or it may be something uniquely
>   specified**. The definite article in English, for both singular and
>   plural nouns, is **the**.

Indefinite article

> An **indefinite article** indicates that its noun is not a particular one
>   (or ones) identifiable to the listener. **It may be something that the
>   speaker is mentioning for the first time, or its precise identity may
>   be irrelevant or hypothetical, or the speaker may be making a general
>   statement about any such thing.**

So point 6 lends to some ambiguity:

1. It could be that **the shortest path** is implied to be unique. (In
   this case I must say the hypothesis and the question are sort of
   misleading)
2. Or it could be that **the shortest path** is only one of the
   possible shortest paths between any two vertices

So if we interpret the hypothesis as per point 1 (i.e. the shortest path means there is a unique shortest path) then the hypothesis is also the answer.

If we interpret the hypothesis as per point 2 then we could consider the following undirected graph:

```
A--5--B
|   /
2  3
| /
 C
```

There is no unique shortest path between A and B
Since we could have both:
AB (cost 5)
AC + CB (cost 2+3 = 5)

So if we interpret the hypothesis not meaning the shortest path is unique and asks you to verify this, then we have demonstrated that there is such graph with no unique shortest path that satisfies all other conditions.

Comment: Talking about "the shortest path" rather than "a shortest path" implies uniqueness, to me. But, if "the" does imply uniqueness, the question is saying "Suppose we have a graph with unique shortest paths. Is it true that shortest paths are unique?"

Comment: Thank you @DavidRicherby you do have a point. then maybe we should work toward an example rather than a counter example. I will keep this answer for now until we hear back, or would you suggest I edit it?

Comment: I'd leave it for now. You've written a good answer to one of the things the question could mean.

Comment: if we consider Any shortest path must be on MST The statement is True, if consider there exists a shortest path on MST this is false. am I right? I means consider two case.

Comment: @AnjelaMinoeu I have added further details to my answer. I suggest you edit your question if you have further details